# array_combine removed duplicate array

Tags: php, arrays, array-combine

Array_combine remove duplicate array

```php
    <?php
        $a1=array("red","red");
        $a2=array("blue","yellow");
        print_r(array_combine($a1,$a2));
    ?>
```

This code give output : `Array ( [red] => yellow )`

But I want output like this: `Array ( [red] => blue [red] => yellow )`

Comment: And if you do `echo $arr['red'];` what do you expect it to output? Blue or yellow? You can't have two keys that is the same.

Comment: I need output like this  Array ( [red] => blue [red] => yellow)

Comment: It's impossible. And that is not an echo. Answer what an echo should output. Your best option is to use a multidimensional array. See here: https://3v4l.org/VTe7d

Comment: It's impossible, to create array, with two the same keys. Check thin in php manual.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Andreas answer is correct. you can do this:

```
$a1 = ['red'];
$a2 = ['blue', 'yellow'];
$a3 = [];
foreach($a1 as $item1) {
  foreach($a2 as $item2) {
    $a3[$item1][] = $item2;
  }
}

print_r($a3);
```

The output:

```
array(1) {
  ["red"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "blue"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "yellow"
  }
}
```

Comment: And I think you have only this way. Do you know, Your codes never working. Because it can't have an array with several same keys. Have good time.

Comment: "your way" does not even have the same input as OP request. So yes, a downvote. Not the same input and not the same output. Is that useful?